# Migrating CSS from Flex 3 to Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex-spark, halo

Is there a guide or document that deals specifically with migrating CSS and style attributes from Flex 3 to Flex 4? I have an application that I'm keeping on the 2006 namespace, but I'm having trouble with a couple concepts, like the halo only styles, the CSS namespacing conventions, and styling child controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://insideria.com/2010/05/transitioning-from-flex-3-to-f.html) is a good start, you'll need to scroll down to the CSS part.